# Remove unchecked value from an array angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, checkbox

I am new to angular js. I have a checkbox with a table .

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-if="report.attributes.message.length > 0" ng-bind="report.attributes.message" ng-click="getcheckedData(report.attributes.message)">{{ report.attributes.message }}</td>
```

Here , I have a method `getcheckedData()`. So,  In that method

```
   var messages = [];

   $scope.getcheckedData = function(SelectedVal) {     
       $("input:checkbox[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
          if ($.inArray(SelectedVal , messages) === -1){
                messages.push(SelectedVal);
           }
        });
         return messages;
  };
```

I have an array which I declared globally,.So, I want to take the value of selected checkbox table data into that array. I am able to get that value in `array`. So, when user unchecks then the value which is unchecked should also get removed from that `array` . So, when user checks then ,
I have given one button on that I am sending all checked messages to the backend.
So, When I uncheck and press the button that time all messages still remain in the array.

```
    $scope.sendAllMessages = function() {      
      uploadService.SendMessagesToQueue(uploadService.currentFileName,$scope.documentType,messages)
     .then(function () {
        }, function (error) {
         $scope.errorMessage = error.status + " : " + error.statusText;
         toastr.error($scope.errorMessage, 'Error : ' + error.status);
         if (error.status === 401) {
             loginService.authenticationError();
         }
       })
       .finally(function () {

        });
     };
```

For button -

```
<button type="submit" ng-click = "sendAllMessages()" class="button-size btn btn-primary">Send  </button>
```

so, How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is **not the angular way** of achieving what you need.

But if you need to do in the same way of Yours, here is the change you should do.

You should remove the value from the array if it is unchecked, using `messages.splice(index, 1);`

**Here is the changed code of your's, without ng-model(not recommended)**

```
var messages = [];

   $scope.getcheckedData = function(SelectedVal) {     

          if ($.inArray(SelectedVal , messages) === -1){
                messages.push(SelectedVal);
           }
           else
           {
           var index = messages.indexOf(SelectedVal)
           messages.splice(index, 1);
           }

         return messages;
  };
```

**To achieve it in angular way, you need to use `ng-model`**

**Here is a sample using Angular**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
   
    $scope.messages = {
      
    };

    $scope.reports = [ { "name": "Sport", "id": "50d5ad" } , {"name": "General", "id": "678ffr" } ];
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-app="app">
    <span ng-repeat="report in reports">
      <label class="checkbox" for="{{report.id}}">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="messages[report.id]" name="group" id="{{report.id}}" />
        {{report.name}}
      </label>
    </span>
    <pre ng-bind="messages | json"></pre>    
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help , Actually it is not working for me. If I check then adds in array but if I uncheck then also it remains in array. But next time when I check then it removes from array.check and uncheck is not proper.

Comment: ok, let me help you. first, which way you want to follow, so that we can proceed accordingly

Comment: First one which I am  using.

Comment: just `console.log(index)`, below your index line and check if you are getting index

Comment: So, Here what is happening, when I first check then It adds in the array, After when I uncheks the same row then still its in the array, but when I again checks then It removes from the array. and that time it shows index 0.

Comment: so,`$.inArray(SelectedVal , messages) === -1` this has some issue. let me check

Comment: got it, you can remove this  `$("input:checkbox[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {` loop

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sravan It is working. Can you please tell me what was the problem ?

Comment: @ganeshk, `$("input:checkbox[type=checkbox]:checked")` this line always gets called only when a checkbox is checked, but not when unchecked. so the loop is getting executes only when it is checked. which is not detecting the unchecking of checkbox. which we changed now.